# Mathematical Modelling Lake volume of water/pollution problem

Tags: mathematical-modeling

A lake contains 200,000m^3$ of water, 7% of which is chemical pollution. Every day 2000m^3$ of polluted water flows out of the lake.

(a) Suppose that every day $2000m^3$ of clean water flows into the lake. If
$P_n$ denotes the volume of pollutant in the lake on day $n$, show that $P_{n+1}= $0.99P_n$. Hence show that it will be 194 complete days before the pollution drops to the safe level deemed to be 1%.

I've shown that $P_{n+1}=0.99P_n$ as every day out of the $2000m^3$ of water that flows out of the lake each $m^3$ contains $P_n/200,000m^3$ of pollutant 
So on day $n+1$,

$P_{n+1}=P_n -2000P_n/200,000$

leading to

$P_{n+1}=0.99P_n$

I also know initially on day $0$ the lake contains

$P_0=0.07 \cdot 200,000=14,000m^3$ of polluted water

I have the solutions to this question and it says solving recursively

$P_n=0.99^nP_0$

which obviously leads to

$2000=0.99^n\cdot 14,000$

I know the 2000 comes from needing the pollution level to be within 1% of the total volume of water and taking logs in this last equation will lead to $nlog0.99=-\log7$ then $n=193.62$ showing that it will be 194 complete days before the pollution drops to the safe level.

My main confusion is solving recursively from $P_{n+1}=0.99P_n$ to $P_n=0.99^nP_0$ I really don't get how one solves this if someone could help it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

We know the relation $P_{n+1} = 0.99P_n$. But we also know that $P_n = 0.99P_{n-1}$, etc... Now we substitute and find
$$ P_{n} = 0.99P_{n-1} = 0.99 (0.99 P_{n-2}) = 0.99 (0.99 (0.99P_{n-3})) = 0.99^{k}P_{n-k}$$
Thus we conclude that $P_n = 0.99^n P_0$ (just plug in $n=k$).

Comment: so $P_k$$=0.99^kP_{n-k}$ ? if so that clears it up thank you!

Comment: If you mean $P_n=0.99^k P_{n-k}$, then you are absolutely right!